# Problems with a converter from seconds to day, hours, minutes, and seconds using Java

Tags: java

I am doing this for a programming class and I keep getting these errors when I go to compile the program in jGrasp:

```
TimeCalculator.java:94: error: variable dblMinutes might not have been initialized
            + timeFormat.format(dblMinutes) + " minutes, and " + timeFormat.format(dblSecondsAfterMinutes) + " seconds.");
                                ^
TimeCalculator.java:94: error: variable dblSecondsAfterMinutes might not have been initialized
            + timeFormat.format(dblMinutes) + " minutes, and " + timeFormat.format(dblSecondsAfterMinutes) + " seconds.");
                                                                                   ^
TimeCalculator.java:98: error: variable dblMinutes might not have been initialized
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + timeFormat.format(dblHours) + " hours, " + timeFormat.format(dblMinutes) + " minutes, and " 
                                                                                                                            ^
TimeCalculator.java:99: error: variable dblSecondsAfterMinutes might not have been initialized
            + timeFormat.format(dblSecondsAfterMinutes) + " seconds.");
                                ^
TimeCalculator.java:101: error: variable dblMinutes might not have been initialized
        else if (dblMinutes >= 1)
                 ^
TimeCalculator.java:102: error: variable dblSecondsAfterMinutes might not have been initialized
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + timeFormat.format(dblMinutes) + " minutes and " + timeFormat.format(dblSecondsAfterMinutes) + " seconds.");  
                                                                                                                                   ^
6 errors
```

My program is supposed to take user input (an amount in seconds) and convert it to days, hours, minutes, and seconds. It then should display the final amount.

Here is my code so far:

```
    /*
This program prompts the user to enter an amount of seconds.
When the user enters an amount, it is stored in a variable and
calculated to how many days, hours, minutes, and seconds there 
are in the given amount of seconds. The information is then 
output for the user to read.

60 seconds = 1 minute
3600 seconds = 1 hour
86400 seconds = 1 day
*/

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class TimeCalculator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DecimalFormat timeFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.#");//used for formatting output

        //declaring needed variables
        String strStartingSeconds;
        double dblStartingSeconds, dblMinutes, dblHours, dblDays, dblSecondsAfterDays, dblSecondsAfterHours, dblSecondsAfterMinutes;

        //get input from user for amount of seconds
        strStartingSeconds = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of seconds: ");

        //convert input to a double
        dblStartingSeconds = Double.parseDouble(strStartingSeconds);

        if (dblStartingSeconds >= 86400)//check to see if it is one day or more
        {
            dblDays = dblStartingSeconds / 86400;//find how many days
            dblSecondsAfterDays = dblStartingSeconds % 86400;//calculate how many seconds are left by finding the remainder

            if (dblSecondsAfterDays >= 3600)//check to see if there is one hour or more
            {
                dblHours = dblSecondsAfterDays / 3600;//find how many hours
                dblSecondsAfterHours = dblSecondsAfterDays % 3600;//calculate how many seconds are left by finding the remainder

                if (dblSecondsAfterHours >= 60)//Check to see if there is one or more minutes
                {
                    dblMinutes = dblSecondsAfterHours / 60;//Calculate how many minutes
                    dblSecondsAfterMinutes = dblSecondsAfterHours % 60;//calculate how many seconds are left by finding the remainder
                }
                else
                {
                    dblMinutes = 0;//If there wasn't enough seconds, assign minutes as 0
                }
            }
            else
                dblHours = 0;//If there wasn't enough hours, assign hours as 0
        }
        else
        {
            dblDays = 0;//assign days as 0 since there wasn't enough seconds

            if (dblStartingSeconds >= 3600)//check to see if there is one hour or more
            {
                dblHours = dblStartingSeconds / 3600;//find how many hours
                dblSecondsAfterHours = dblStartingSeconds % 3600;//calculate how many seconds are left by finding the remainder

                if (dblSecondsAfterHours >= 60)//Check to see if there is one or more minutes
                {
                    dblMinutes = dblSecondsAfterHours / 60;//Calculate how many minutes
                    dblSecondsAfterMinutes = dblSecondsAfterHours % 60;//calculate how many seconds are left by finding the remainder
                }
                else
                {
                    dblMinutes = 0;//assign minutes as 0 since there wasn't enough seconds
                }
            }
            else
            {               
                dblHours = 0;//assign hours as 0 since there wasn't enough hours

                if (dblStartingSeconds >= 60)//Check to see if there is one or more minutes
                {
                    dblMinutes = dblStartingSeconds / 60;//Calculate how many minutes
                    dblSecondsAfterMinutes = dblStartingSeconds % 60;//calculate how many seconds are left by finding the remainder
                }
                else
                {                   
                    dblMinutes = 0;//Assign minutes as 0 since there wasn't enough seconds                          
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + timeFormat.format(dblStartingSeconds) + " seconds.");//Displays how many seconds there was
                }
            }
        }
        //Display the correct amount of time based on whether or not there was enough seconds for days, hours, or minutes
        if (dblDays >= 1)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + timeFormat.format(dblDays) + " days, " + timeFormat.format(dblHours) + " hours, " 
            + timeFormat.format(dblMinutes) + " minutes, and " + timeFormat.format(dblSecondsAfterMinutes) + " seconds.");
        }
        else if (dblHours >= 1)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + timeFormat.format(dblHours) + " hours, " + timeFormat.format(dblMinutes) + " minutes, and " 
            + timeFormat.format(dblSecondsAfterMinutes) + " seconds.");
        }
        else if (dblMinutes >= 1)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + timeFormat.format(dblMinutes) + " minutes and " + timeFormat.format(dblSecondsAfterMinutes) + " seconds.");  
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + timeFormat.format(dblStartingSeconds) + " seconds.");

        System.exit(0);//close application
    }
}
```

I have no joke, spent hours looking through this and can't find what I'm doing wrong! I'm pretty new to programming, so anything will help (I probably did something stupid and obvious to an expert programmer).

Thanks,
-Cashe

Comment: _"variable dblMinutes might not have been initialized"_ Initialize  it then !

Comment: The error statement is self explanatory. You have an execution path where some variable is not initialized.

Comment: You have conditionals around some initializations. This means those initializations might not run. Initialize explicitly.

Comment: I tried doing that, but I always managed to get 0 (the initialized value) as the output. But after going over it again, I found the problem with that! Sorry for the stupid question. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double dblMinutes = 0;

Read about initializing fields here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: Yeah, I did that at one point. But I kept getting 0 as the output (that's what my initialization value was). I thought it was because I initialized it as that; but after going over it again, I found the real problem with the program. Thanks for the help though! Sorry for the stupid question

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your initialization issue...  [java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) is your best friend when dealing with converting units of time.

Comment: We haven't learned about java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit yet in my Java Programming class, but I'm sure we will soon (I am only in chapter 3). I'll definitely look into that though! Thanks!